# Tomdoc - using multiline Ruby comments

Tags: ruby, github

I notice that tomdoc.org exclusively uses single-line comments. But the very idea of in-code documentation seems like a natural fit with Ruby's multiline comments (`=begin ... =end`). Does anyone know if there's any special reason why Tomdoc sticks with single-line comments? Or is it simply preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why Tomdoc uses the single-line style, but here are some reasons I prefer it:

- The vertical wall of octothorpes more clearly separates comments
  from code.
- Surrounding comments with `=begin` and `=end` increases the vertical height of comments that are already spread out enough.
- Octothorped comments are the Ruby standard, and following the standard makes it easier to read other people's code.
- `=begin` and `=end` have to be on the first column, fouling up the indentation.

Comment: I disagree with your third point. Every syntactic feature in Ruby is Ruby standard. I think your fourth point is the most convincing.

Comment: Agree that indentation is important. That's a good reason to prefer `#`.